# Application of the Koszul formula

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

given

$\mathfrak{h} = span_{\mathbb{R}}\{ P=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ,
Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
h=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \}$.
With the left-invariant metric, the Koszul formula gives

$\nabla_P P = 0$

$\nabla_Q P = -1/2h$

$ \nabla_h P = -1/2Q $

$\nabla_P Q = 1/2h$

$\nabla_Q Q = 0$

$\nabla_h Q = 1/2p$

$\nabla_p h = - 1/2 Q$

$\nabla_Q h = 1/2 P$

$\nabla_h h = 0$.

My question is then how to get to the results provided by the Koszul formula? I am a bit confused about that since it is the first time I am working with it.

Comment: See the computation [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwip-6DDrN_5AhWItqQKHWQJCMQQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1604.04934&usg=AOvVaw39yBv0N5TUKdYePsP_vyou), it is section 5, the case of the Heisenberg Lie algebra.

Comment: My main goal is to figure out a way to compute sectional curvature on low dimensional matrices. I stumbled upon notes that used the Kozsul formula to obtain sectional curvatures on matrices. I thought the real Heisenberg Lie algebra might be a good place to start to use it as an easy example.  The Koszul formula I am talking about is: $2 \langle \nabla_X Y , Z \rangle = X ( \langle Y , Z \rangle ) + Y (\langle X , Z \rangle) - Z (\langle X , Y \rangle) - \langle Y , [X,Z] \rangle - \langle X , [Y,Z] \rangle - \langle  Z, [Y,X] \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Lie group endowed with a left-invariant metric and $X, Y,Z$ be left-invariant vector fields on $G$, then the Koszul formula says
$$
\langle \nabla_X Y,Z\rangle=\frac{1}{2}
\biggl(\langle [X,Y],Z \rangle - \langle [X,Z],Y\rangle - \langle [Y,Z],X\rangle \biggr).
$$
For the Heisenberg Lie group this is computed in the above paper in section $5$. So you can see the computation there.
They define vector fields $X_1,X_2,X_3$ corresponding to your $P,Q,h$, and compute all $\nabla_{X_i}X_j$. The result is
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{X_i}X_i & = 0,\\
\nabla_{X_1}X_2 & =\frac{1}{2}X_3 = - \nabla_{X_2}X_1,\\
\nabla_{X_1}X_3 & =-\frac{1}{2}X_2 = - \nabla_{X_3}X_1,\\ 
\nabla_{X_2}X_3 & =\frac{1}{2}X_1 = - \nabla_{X_3}X_2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does this technique only apply to Lie groups endowed with a left-invariant metric?

Comment: No, it works more generally. Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, and let $\nabla:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ be a connection. If $\nabla$ satisfies the conditions of the Levi-Civita connection, then it satisfies the Koszul Formula:

$
\langle\nabla_{X}Y,Z\rangle=\dfrac{1}{2}(X\langle Y, Z\rangle+Y\langle Z, X\rangle-Z\langle X, Y\rangle
-\langle Y,[X, Z]\rangle-\langle Z,[Y, X]\rangle+\langle X,[Z, Y]\rangle).
$.

Comment: My goal is to eventually use that formula for computing the sectional curvature on St(4,2) Stiefel manifold of dimension $4 \times 2$, would that be possible with that formula?

Comment: In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01834) the sectional curvature of Stiefel manifolds is computed relative to some Riemannian metric, see section $3$.